# How to remove the enclosing brackets when bquote contains multiple expressions?

Tags: r, metaprogramming, non-standard-evaluation

```r
bquote({
  A <- 4
  print(A)
})
```

output:

```r
{
    A <- 4
    print(A)
}
```

What can I do so that the output is simply:

```r
A <- 4
print(A)
```

Comment: That is no longer a valid object.

Answer (score 2):

As @G.Grothendieck says in comments, you can't get rid of the brackets in the object, but you could get that output by doing:

```
for (i in 2:3) {
   print(b[[i]])
}
```

Or, overkill:

```r
class(b) <- "foo"
print.foo <- function(x) for (i in 2:length(x)) print(x[[i]])
b
```